# ¿Cómo agregar un separador a cadenas largas en PHP cada X cantidad de caracteres guardando las palabras completas?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con una App Android la cual recoge texto de mi servidor. Luego ese texto puede ser leído por voz en la App mediante el engine TTS de Android.

[TTS no puede leer cadenas de más de 4,000 caracteres de un solo golpe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/108826/29967) y muchas veces mis cadenas tienen una extensión mayor.

Mi solución ha sido ir dividiendo el contenido con un separador y luego hacer partes para irlas pasando a TTS. Eso lo hago la mayoría de veces desde Android, cuando es texto que voy construyendo por partes pequeñas, a cada parte le pongo el separador y listo.

En este caso concreto extraigo texto bastante largo en un solo bloque, es texto de la base de datos con bastantes párrafos y quisiera enviárselo a Android desde el servidor con un separador cada `4,000<` caracteres.

El problema es que no puedo hacer una separación arbitraria, porque muchas palabras quedarían cortadas por la mitad.

Me explico. Supongamos una cadena larga:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
       *caracter 4000
```

Una división arbitraria me partiría en dos la palabra `ipsum`, resultando:

- parte 1: `mucho texto hasta lorem i`
- parte 2: `psum más mucho texto`

TTS lee esto mal, porque se detiene en `i` y luego da como un salto para continuar con `pusm` y el resto del texto.

Quisiera entonces en PHP poder colocar al texto un separador **cada 4,000 caracteres o lo máximo posible, pero salvando las palabras completas, incluyendo los posibles signos como comas, puntos, comillas, etc**.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Me interesa dejar la cadena intacta, agregando solamente el separador donde corresponda, algo así (suponiendo que mi separador es `|`):

```
Muchísimo texto ... Lorem| ipsum dolor sit amet muchísimo |más, texto
                           *caracter 4000                     *caracter 8000
```

Aquí, dado que el caracter 4,000 dejaría la palabra `ipsum` entrecortada, retrocedemos para dividir después de `Lorem`. En el segundo separador, dado que la división iría antes de la coma, retrocedemos también y lo ponemos antes de `más`.

He visto la posibilidad de hacerlo con `str_split`, pero me devuelve un array de cadenas y yo quiero la cadena completa. Además, ¿cómo manejar lo más complicado que es evitar que las palabras queden cortadas?

Comment: Daríamos por supuesto que el texto está bien formateado. ¿No? Ejemplo: un solo espacio entre palabras, espacio después de un signo de puntuación pero no antes, etc.

Comment: @PHPMyguel no lo puedo asegurar. Estamos hablando de miles y miles de párrafos en una base de datos y puede que haya casos (no muchos) en los que errores como los que mencionas aparezcan. De todos modos, si fuera un problema esos problemas los podría corregir haciendo `UPDATE` combinado con  `REPLACE`. Otra cosa que olvidé comentar es que el texto tiene etiquetas HTML como `<p>`, `<span>`, `<br />`, y puede tener enlaces como `<a="http://...">` y cosas así.

Comment: @A.Cedano Podrías utilizar `wordwrap()`, el problema podría ser las etiquetas html del texto

Comment: @Xerif hice pruebas con `wordwrap()` como has sugerido y parce hacer lo que necesito. Ningún problema con las etiquetas HTML. Estoy devolviendo los datos en un JSON: `$arrData=array(); foreach ($arrData as $k=>$v){
 $arrData[$k]['texto'] = wordwrap($v["texto"], 3996, " | ", true);   
}
$json=json_encode($arrData,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); echo $json;`. Agradecería una respuesta tuya para dar el tema por cerrado.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me alegro, ahí te dejo una respuesta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos insertar un separador en las cadenas de texto cada **X** carácteres utilizando la función [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.wordwrap.php) de PHP. Esta función por defecto inserta el carácter que le indiquemos en el tercer parametro evitando por defecto romper palabras.

Por ejemplo

```
<?php
$texto = "Y en lo que toca a la carta de amores, pondrás por firma: «Vuestro hasta la muerte, el Caballero de la Triste Figura». Y hará poco al caso que vaya de mano ajena, porque, a lo que yo me sé acordar, Dulcinea no sabe escribir ni leer y en toda su vida ha visto letra mía ni carta mía, porque mis amores y los suyos han sido siempre platónicos, sin estenderse a más que a un honesto mirar.";

echo wordwrap($texto, 20, "|||");
```

Resultado

```
Y en lo que toca a|||la carta de amores,|||pondrás por firma:|||«Vuestro hasta la|||muerte, el Caballero|||de la Triste|||Figura». Y hará|||poco al caso que|||vaya de mano ajena,|||porque, a lo que yo|||me sé acordar,|||Dulcinea no sabe|||escribir ni leer y|||en toda su vida ha|||visto letra mía ni|||carta mía, porque|||mis amores y los|||suyos han sido|||siempre platónicos,|||sin estenderse a|||más que a un|||honesto mirar.
```

> **wordwrap ( string $str [, int $width = 75 [, string $break = "\n" [, bool $cut = false ]]] )**
>
> Ajusta un string hasta un número dado de caracteres

Answer (score 1):

A modo de ejercicio y sin poder de momento invertirle un poco más de tiempo, he desarrollado una pequeña función que se aproxima a lo que necesitas. Habría que contemplar casos concretos para añadirle condiciones, pero a grandes rasgos podría ser un punto de partida.

**PHP**

```
$str = "En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.";

$mostrar = trocea_frases($str, 20);
var_dump($mostrar);

function trocea_frases ($frase, $caracteres_por_trozo) {
    $palabras = explode(" ", $frase);
    $n_caracteres = 0;
    $trozos_frase = array();
    $frase_recompuesta = '';

    foreach ($palabras as $palabra) {
        $n_caracteres = $n_caracteres + strlen($palabra) +1;
        $frase_recompuesta .= $palabra . ' ';

        if ($n_caracteres > $caracteres_por_trozo) {
            array_push($trozos_frase, $frase_recompuesta);
            $frase_recompuesta = '';
            $n_caracteres = 0;
        }
    }

    return $trozos_frase;
}
```

A grandes rasgos lo que tengo es una función que recibe el texto entero que necesitas trocear y el número de caracteres por los que necesitas dividirlo y que devuelve un array con cada uno de los trozos que resultan de ese proceso.

Lo que hago es considerar una palabra como el conjunto de caracteres anteriores a un "espacio" y la función consigue de esa manera que no se haga un "trozo" que deje una palabra a la mitad.

Como avisé, faltaría mucho trabajo por hacer porque tan solo funcionaría si el texto está perfectamente formado. En el caso de las etiquetas, por ejemplo `<p>Hola` se consideraría como la misma palabra y un sin fin de salvedades que deberían ser corregidas.

Estoy seguro de que existe alguna manera mejor de hacerse, quizás usando alguna otra función de **PHP** pero esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido sin dedicarle un trabajo de investigación muy amplio.

Comment: Se me olvidó mencionar que las pruebas las he hecho con una cadena que no se acerca ni por asomo a las longitudes que tu necesitas manejar, así que no sabría decirte si habría problemas de desbordamiento en mi función.