# ¿Cómo puedo dividir una cadena en un máximo de N caracteres de forma no arbitraria en Java (sin librerías externas)?

Tags: java, string

Necesito dividir unas cadenas largas en Java a partir de `n` caracteres, pero sin romper las palabras en dos.

En PHP existe una función `wordwrap` que permite hacer una división por palabras, de modo que no rompe la palabra de forma arbitraría.

Por ejemplo, si tengo que dividir esta palabra: **`Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...`** en fragmentos de no más de 20 caracteres, en lugar de cortar la palabra así:

- Fragmento 1: `Lorem ipsum dolor si`
- Fragmento 2: `t amet...`

Me la divide así:

- Fragmento 1: `Lorem ipsum dolor`
- Fragmento 2: `sit amet`

Busco algo parecido en Java. Lo que he visto hasta ahora sugiere usar librerías externas, pero quiero implementarlo en código nativo de Java (una función que ya exista, o crear una).

¿Existe esta función? ¿Si no existe, cómo podría hacer esto?

Pregunta relacionada sobre el mismo tema: [¿Cómo agregar un separador a cadenas largas en PHP cada X cantidad de caracteres guardando las palabras completas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/215680/29967)

Comment: Con StringTokenizer podrías implementarlo. Esta función te separa un String por el carácter que le indiques.

Comment: Java tiene el método `split()` al que puedes pasar un regex para separar las palabras (por ejemplo, `cadena.split("\\W+");`. A partir de ahi, es sencillo contar las letras de cada parabra para dividir las filas

Answer (score 6):

Como te decía en mi comentario, una opción de las muchas posibles es usar `split`, que en una de sus sobrecargas admite un carácter, y devuelve un array de `String` con la cadena separada por dicho carácter. Luego puedes ir añadiendo a alguna variable cada palabra teniendo en cuenta el tamaño máximo que esperas en la fila. Posiblemente haya mejores formas que la que te muestro aqui, pero te puede ayudar a hacerte una idea:

```
public static List<String> wordWrap(String cadena, int maxCaracteres)
{
    String[] palabras= cadena.split(" ");
    List<String> filas= new ArrayList<String>();
    String fila="";
    for(String palabra:palabras){
        if (fila.length()+palabra.length()<maxCaracteres){
            fila+=" " + palabra;
        }
        else{
            filas.add(fila);
            fila=palabra;
        }
    }
    filas.add(fila);
    return filas;
}
```

Este método devuelve un `List<String>`, siendo cada elemento una linea tras aplicar el algoritmo descrito.

Modo de uso:

```
String test="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
List<String> filas= wordWrap(test,15);
for(String fila:filas){
    System.out.println(fila); 
}
```

Ejemplos de salida:

```
wordWrap(test,20); 
//Lorem ipsum dolor
//sit amet
wordWrap(test,15); 
//Lorem ipsum
//dolor sit amet

wordWrap(test,12);
//Lorem ipsum
//dolor sit
//amet
wordWrap(test,5);
//Lorem
//ipsum
//dolor
//sit
//amet
```

<sub>P.D. Debes tener en cuenta que para que funcione, debe haber un espacio entre las cada palabra para poder separarlas correctamente</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Manteniendo la idea de la función que se quiere imitar (devolver un único String, con las líneas ya separadas), podríamos hacer algo como

```
public class WordWrapTest {

    public static String wordWrap(String s, int l, String returnLine) {
        String[] words = s.split(" ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int lastReturn = 0;
        for (String w : words) {
            if (sb.length() + w.length() - lastReturn >= l) {
                // si la palabra es demasiado larga, no podemos hacer nada
                if (sb.length() == lastReturn) {
                    sb.append(w).append(returnLine);
                } else {
                    sb.append(returnLine);
                    lastReturn = sb.length() - 1;
                    sb.append(w);
                }
            } else {
                sb.append(w);
            }
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String wordWrap(String s, int l) {
        return wordWrap(s, l, "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(wordWrap(
                "En un lugar de la Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo ...",
                17));
    }
}
```

Va añadiendo separadores cada `l` caracteres, teniendo en cuenta de que si una palabra es demasiado larga (si usamos líneas muy cortas y estamos escribiendo palabras como *esternocleidomastoideo*) no podemos cortarla.